# Flutter can't execute FirebaseCrashlytics run script

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

faced with issue when try to build Flutter application with Firebase Crashlytics and got this error.

```
/Users/andrew/folder/ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/run: line 2: 
: command not found
/Users/andrew/folder/ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/run: line 38: 
: command not found
/Users/andrew/folder/ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/run: line 41: 
: command not found
/Users/andrew/folder/ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/run: line 77: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

There is my settings.

[image]

Does anybody faced with same issue?

Previous version "Fabric" works fine.

Comment: Also I've put   pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics' pod 'Firebase/Analytics' in podfile ,but still same issue

Comment: I've seen that error go away after cleaning the build and rerunning the app.